# VBA gives error if the worksheet is not visible

Tags: visible, worksheet

At my codes, there are some refers to other worksheets, but I don't know why, if those sheets are not visible, macro gives error: "Visible Method of Worksheet class failed".

Could you guys help me?

Codes starts like this, and I get the error just with ' `Worksheets("Ders_TEMP").Visible`

```
Sub Ders_Rapor()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRowXLC = Worksheets("Egitim Bilgileri").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Ders_Adi_Sec.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Egitim Bilgileri").Range("C2:C" & LastRowXLC & "").Value
Ders_Adi_Sec.Show

Worksheet_Bilgiler = "Egitim Bilgileri"
If Ders_Adi_Sec.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then MsgBox "Lütfen Ders Seçiniz"
If Ders_Adi_Sec.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then GoTo Son
Ders_Adi_2 = Ders_Adi_Sec.ComboBox1.Value

Dim Found_Ders As Range
Set Found_Ders = Sheets("Egitim Bilgileri").Columns("C").Find(Ders_Adi_2, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Ders_Adi_Row = Found_Ders.Row

Ders_Sheet_Adi = Worksheets("Egitim Bilgileri").Cells(Ders_Adi_Row, 1).Value
Ders_Satir_bul = Found_Ders.Row

' Ders_Satir_bul degeri, aratilan egitimin, "Egitim_Bilgileri" sayfasindaki satir numarasidir.

Worksheets("Ders_TEMP").Visible
Worksheets("Egitim Bilgileri").Visible
Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Visible
Worksheets(Worksheet_Bilgiler).Cells(Ders_Satir_bul, 3).Copy
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Ders_TEMP").Activate
Worksheets("Ders_TEMP").Select
Worksheets("Ders_TEMP").Range("A2:J2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Worksheets("Ders_TEMP").Range("A49:J49").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Worksheets("Ders_TEMP").Range("A96:J96").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault, I forgot to put " = True" after .visible statements.